# downwards arrow in R-plot axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have a Variable named **\LW$_\downarrow$** in Latex. 
As you can imagine, i would like to use the same phrase as axis label and add the Unit which is [W/m²] or [W m^-2]

I managed to do this:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(2:6))
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression(LW%down%. ))
```

but

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression(LW%down% )) #no point behind the second %
```

gives "Error:

> unexpected ')' in: "  geom_point()+   labs(x=expression(LW%down% )"

and

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=paste(expression(LW%down%. ), "[W/m²]"))
```

gives this: with %down% as word

[image]

unfortunately not very helpful.

I hope someone can help. I have a lot of plots so I hope someone so manual editing with inkscape does not really sound like a good option.

---

tyumru gave me a good hint to the right direction with

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression("LW"%down%"[W/m²]"))
```

Whe I try to put the arrow in subscript with

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression("LW"[%down%]"[W/m²]"))
```

Unfortunately I get

Error: unexpected SPECIAL in:
"  geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression("LW"[%down%"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression("LW"%down%"[W/m²]"))
```

**EDIT:**

Ok this is kind of a hack but it works. In the documentation of [plotmath](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) you can see that %down% works like an operator, so it requires two strings before and after. The two empy strings serve for that:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression(paste(LW[""%down%""]," [W/m²]")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey tyumuru, yes thats almost it. I woul love the arrow to be a subscript. unfortunately with labs(x=expression("LW"[%down%]"[W/m²]")) I get Error: unexpected SPECIAL in:
"  geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression("LW"[%down%"

Answer (score 2):

From `help('plotmath')`, you can use `group('[',w / m^2, ']')` to wrap your units in delimiters

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression(LW %down% group("[", w/m^2, "]")))
```

[image]

or `bgroup` if you want scaleable delimiters

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression(LW %down% bgroup("[", over(w, m^2), "]")))
```

[image]